Formatter Options missing in Delphi 12 after update
I would like to automatically format my Delphi code, but after the RAD Studio 12 update to version 29.0.53571.9782, I don't have anymore the Formatter Options page in Tools > Options > Language > Formatter.
I still have the formatter options for C++ (clang-format) in Tools > Options > Language > C++ > Formatting.
Do you know how to restore it?

As an alternative you can use GExperts or CnPack plugin. Both have their own code formatter tool.

You may read this information about the formatting option:
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/What%27s_New#Moving_Deprecated_Features

Moving Deprecated Features
In RAD Studio 12.0 Athens, we are moving some old and unsupported tools out of the core product installation, making them available as add-ons:

VCL Translation Support.
Modeling. Note that you must install this if you want to use Delphi code formatting, and it is available in the Technology section of the installer.


